# How do you put values over a simple bar chart in Excel?

Tags: data-visualization, excel

I'd like to put values over a simple bar/column chart in excel.

A [similar question was asked for R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/how-to-put-values-over-bars-in-barplot-in-r), and I know how to get my data into R, but not how to make the charts. What I'm doing is very simple seems easier to do in Excel than learning how to do it in R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're using Excel 2007, data labels are added through the "Data Labels" selection.   As shown below, cells A2:A5 contain the data Items.    Cells B2:B5 contain the data Values.

1) Select cells A2:B5

2) Select "Insert"

3) Select the desired "Column" type graph

4) Click on the graph to make sure it is selected, then select "Layout"

5) Select "Data Labels" ("Outside End" was selected below.)

If you don't want the Values as the Labels, you can click on the desired label, click twice so that it's the only thing selected, and then enter your new label information in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for (PITA to find that by googling for it). I'm in Excel 2010, but it works the same way in there.

Comment: Ah-ha.... I googled PITA to figure out what that means.

Comment: It's a useful acronym - slightly more polite than saying what it stands for :)